# Why youtube-v3-api stopped working?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are using youtube-v3-api for quite some time now but suddenly it started responding with error 403 saying that the access needs to be enabled.

Here is the error message:

```
{
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "usageLimits",
      "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project {projectId} before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project={projectId} then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
      "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
      "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project={projectId}"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project {projectId} before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project={projectId} then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
}
```

But the api is enabled and it worked for months:
[image: dashboard]

We use the api with oauth2 tokens and with API keys as well but we receive the same error for both.

What can be the problem?

I tried to disable and reenable the API but that didn't help.

**Update**:

Google support suggested that the issue maybe caused by the daily quota limit which is set to 0.
[image: Quotas]
However we cannot edit this quota as shown in the picture although we have all admin rights to do so.

Does anyone experienced this? How could we raise the quota?
We already filled out a quota limit extension form and waiting for the response but I think we should be able to set to quota to a workable level on the developer console.

Comment: In case you need more details:


**Org name**
falcon.io


**Org ID**
483073740112


**Project name**
FalconSocial-GooglePlusPages


**Project ID**
falconsocial.com:api-project-926200008649


**Project number**
926200008649

Comment: We have been in contact with Google Cloud support but they insist on this not being a Google Cloud issue. This is a big issue for us since we have customers relying on this working. The level of support is non existent from Googles side.

Comment: Google support is kind of s***t. I Fillout 2 Forms already with no answer. I also leavve my BankAccount for debit. No result until now